# Android - appcompat-v7:27.1.1 error after adding facebook sdk

Tags: android

These are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

When I add `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'` then it "breaks" `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` with the error: `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification`

Some answers from [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) suggest that I have to look at all the libraries but I can't see what's wrong here:

[image]

Can someone explain it? I'm complete newbie in android and I must say it's a horrendous mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'`

Comment: Nope I get this error: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0]    
Should I change the API level to higher?

Comment: It looks like changing from min API from 14 to 18 and probably also facebook sdk from 4.0.1 to current 4.35.0 did the trick. Thanks!